# How to rewrite base64_encode from PHP to Swift 3 in iOS ?

Tags: php, ios, swift, base64, encode

how to implement this code from **PHP** to **iOS Swift 3** ?

```
base64_encode("qywueifk85oflmvJ");
```

And result is something like this:

> GJXIFSs5tA0LRmCANJS98g==

Comment: ????? @AgamBanga that is not explain for this

Comment: It *is* a duplicate. The code that you accepted below is even contained in one of the answers to the other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you could create an extension on the String class.
This would look like this:

```
extension String 
{
    func toBase64() -> String 
    {
        return Data(self.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```

You can then simply call the function on the string.

```
let stringToEncode = "qywueifk85oflmvJ"
let encodedString = stringToEncode.toBase64()
```

If you don't want to use an extension you can simply create the function:

```
func base64(from: String) -> String 
{
    return Data(from.utf8).base64EncodedString()
}
```

This would make the call look like:

```
let encodedString = base64(from: "qywueifk85oflmvJ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JoasHoogendijk